# Safety of placement new and std::destroy_at in typed std::array?

Tags: c++, c++17, destructor, memory-alignment, placement-new

Consider the following example:

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>

class trivial
{
public:
    trivial() = default;
    trivial(int a, float b) : m_a(a), m_b(b) {}

private:
    int m_a;
    float m_b;
};

template<typename T>
void write(T& arr, size_t idx, int a, float b)
{
    ::new(static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(arr[idx]))) trivial(a, b);
}

template<typename T>
void destroy(T& arr, size_t idx)
{
    std::destroy_at(std::addressof(arr[idx]));
}

int main()
{
    auto arr = std::array<trivial, 20>();

    write(arr, 3, 10, 20.0f);
    destroy(arr, 3);
}
```

Is using placement `new` and `std::destroy_at` in-place safe to do for arbitrary (but reasonable) data arrays? Are there any risks or potential undefined behavior here, or portability issues? Assuming that we won't try to assign to a destroyed value, which I understand is undefined.

I've noticed that this approach benchmarks better than using `std::aligned_storage` and `reinterpret_cast`, largely due to `std::launder` serving as an optimization blocker. If I'm comfortable with the additional limitations of storing my values in an `std::array` (such as requiring a default constructor), is this an acceptable use case?

Comment: You have double destruction. When `arr` goes out of scope, it'll destroy all its elements, including the one you called `destroy_at` on. I think it's UB, but not 100% sure (the destructor is trivial here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have double destruction of the third element of the `std::array arr`. Once by explicit destruction (the `destroy` call) and the other by the implicit destruction (when `arr` goes out of scope). This leads to undefined behavior as per the C++ standard.

> **15.4 Destructors [[class.dtor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.dtor)**
>   ...
>   [16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.dtor#16) Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists; the behavior is undefined if the destructor is invoked for an object whose lifetime has ended. [ Example: If the destructor for an automatic object is explicitly invoked, and the block is subsequently left in a manner that would ordinarily invoke implicit destruction of the object, the behavior is undefined. —end example ]

The example in the above quote is somewhat similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: And a double construction. If the order of write and destroy is switched, then the bahavior will be fixed:twice construction and destruction on same address. But the snippet is still dangerous.

Comment: Is there any way around this double destruction? Consider a situation like, say, a hash set implementation where I know which cells are valid and which aren't. Can I achieve this in-place behavior safely without using `std::aligned_storage` (or more specifically, `std::launder`)?

Comment: When variables of different storage durations are mixed up as in this particular case, I do not think it will be safe. Even if it were, such code would probably not pass code review. :)